# Counting vowels with consonants

Tags: java, string, count

I have made a program to count the number of vowels and consonants in an inputted string:

```
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.print("Enter a string ");
    String phrase = in.nextLine();

int i, length, vowels = 0;
int consonants = 0;
boolean y = false;
String j;
length = phrase.length();
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
{



        j = "" + phrase.charAt(i);


     boolean isAVowel = "aeiou".contains(j.toLowerCase());
     boolean y = "y".contains(j.toLowerCase());


     if(isAVowel){
         vowels++;
     }else if(isAVowel && y){
     vowels++;
    consonants++;
//}else if(y && !(isAVowel)){
//   vowels++;
      }else{
      consonants++;
      }


System.out.println("The number of vowels in \"" +phrase+"\" is "+ vowels+".\n\nThe number of consonants is "+consonants+".\n\n");
```

When "y" is by itself it says its a consonant, it should be a vowel. Where do I state this?

Comment: btw: instead of using substring(i, i+1) in the loop, you can simply use phrase.charAt(i) to iterate over all characters within the string. This approach increases efficiency and readability.

Comment: so like:    
  j = phrase.substring(i);

?

Comment: Actually more like: j = "" + phrase.charAt(i);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things going on here:

1. j.equalsIgnoreCase("a,e,i,o,u") will check if j (a length 1 string) is the string "a,e,i,o,u", which is almost certainly not what you want (since it's always false and therefore you set y=true for every consonant). Instead, consider setting a boolean value to false at the beginning of each iteration and setting it to true in the vowel branches. Then, if that variable is true, you know that this time you saw a vowel. Or just have the else branch.
2. You initialize y to false outside the loop, but once y is true it never gets reset, and so for each letter you will run the if (y == true) block.
3. Right now, your system only accounts for words with 1 y and no vowels. If you enter "yyy", you'll get 1 vowel & 2 consonants.

Stylistically, there are a lot of other changes you can make to make your program easier to read through and debug. Here are a few:

You don't have to do "== true" when checking a bool. For example, instead of "if (y == true)" just do "if (y)".

All the vowels are handled the same, so you don't need separate branches for each. For example, you could have:

```
if (j.equalsIgnoreCase("a") 
    || j.equalsIgnoreCase("e")
    || j.equalsIgnoreCase("i")
    || ...)
{
    vowels++;
}
```

In fact, you can simplify this further by checking against a collection of vowel values, using a regex, or in this case, simply using contains:

```
boolean isAVowel = "aeiou".contains(j.toLowerCase());
```

Consider counting y's separately, so you keep track of vowels, ys, and constants in 3 separate counters. Then, at the end you can decide whether to add ys to vowels or consonants.

Finally, add a `System.out.println("vowels = " + vowels + ", consonants = " + consonants + "...")` to the inside of your loop during the debugging stage. This will make it a lot easier to see what is going on and where things start to go wrong.

Comment: typo? `which is almost certainly what you want`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should simply use regex

```
String phrase = in.nextLine();
int consonants = phrase.replaceAll("a|e|o|u|i", "").length();
int vowels = phrase.replaceAll("[^a|e|o|u|i|y]", "").length();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to understand what exactly you want to do with 'y' so have counted them seperately. **It is necessary to first remove all the non-word characters from the input**.

I have modified your code (though haven't optimized):

```
System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
String origphrase = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
String phrase = origphrase.replaceAll("\\W","");
int i, length, vowels = 0;
int consonants = 0;
int ys=0;
String j;

length = phrase.length();
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
  j = "" + phrase.charAt(i);
  boolean isAVowel = "aeiou".contains(j.toLowerCase());
  boolean y = "y".contains(j.toLowerCase());
  if(isAVowel){
    vowels++;
  }else if(y){
    ys++;
  }else{
    consonants++;
  }
}

System.out.println("Phrase:"+origphrase);
System.out.println("Vowels:"+vowels);
System.out.println("Consonants:"+consonants);
System.out.println("Y's:"+ys);
```

Comment: Add `ys` to `vowels` or `consonants` where you want to

Answer (score 0):

The following recursive function returns the number of vowels in an input string

```
public static int vc(String s){
    if(s.length() - 1 < 0) return 0;
    return ((("aeiou".indexOf((s.charAt(s.length()-1)+"").toLowerCase()) >= 0 ? 1 : 0))  
    + vc((s = s.substring(0,s.length()-1))));
}
```